# map value of nested dictionary to new column in dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following nested dictionary for each row in a DataFrame.

```
dictionary
{'https://twitter.com/tonythehuff/status/927186407789137920/photo/1': {'malicious': False}}
{'http://giveaway.amazon.com\\__CONNECTIONPOOL_ERROR__': {'malicious': False}}
{'http://pcktpro.com\\__CONNECTIONPOOL_ERROR__': {'malicious': True}}
```

I'd like to create a new column by mapping the value of the nested dictionary. The rows from the new column named 'malicious' look like

```
malicious
False
False
True
```

Would there be any efficient way to get the value of the nested dictionary as above?

Data:

```
{'dictionary': [
    {'https://twitter.com/tonythehuff/status/927186407789137920/photo/1': {'malicious': False}},
    {'http://giveaway.amazon.com\\__CONNECTIONPOOL_ERROR__': {'malicious': False}},
    {'http://pcktpro.com\\__CONNECTIONPOOL_ERROR__': {'malicious': True}}]}
```

Comment: Your 'nested dictionary' isn't useful Python code. Please include the actual code you are working with (as written, you have 3 dictionaries which aren't assigned to any variables). Edit: I've just noticed you referred to a 'dataframe'. If you are working with Pandas, please tag appropriately and update the code/question to state this explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a list comprehension with a double loop should do the job:

```
df['malicious'] = [d.get('malicious') for outer_d in df['dictionary'] for d in outer_d.values()]
```

or you can try the following code that creates a DataFrame out of the "dictionary" column and gets the value under the "malicious" key using `str.get`:

```
df['malicious'] = (pd.DataFrame(df['dictionary'].tolist()).set_axis([0]*len(df), axis=1)
                   .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
                   .first()[0]
                   .str.get('malicious'))
```

Output:

```
                                          dictionary  malicious
0  {'https://twitter.com/tonythehuff/status/92718...      False
1  {'http://giveaway.amazon.com\__CONNECTIONPOOL_...      False
2  {'http://pcktpro.com\__CONNECTIONPOOL_ERROR__'...       True
```

Comment: Code works well but what if df['dictionary'] is none, then how do I treat Nonetype value?